# I want to display numbers from 0 to 100 clockwise in canvas

Tags: android, canvas

I want to print numbers from 0 to 100 clockwise on canvas it will work when we have values from 0 to 12 but once i changed the values or increased the it is stopped working in my case can anyone help me here?

```
private int[] mClockHours = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,11,12};
private void drawNumeral(Canvas canvas) {
    mPaint.setTextSize(fontSize);
    for (int number : mClockHours) {
        String tmp = String.valueOf(number);
        mPaint.getTextBounds(tmp, 0, tmp.length(), mRect);
        double angle = Math.PI / 6 * (number - 2);

        Log.d("drawNumeral", "number: "+number);
        Log.d("drawNumeral", "Math.PI: "+Math.PI);
        Log.d("drawNumeral", "angle: "+angle);
        Log.d("drawNumeral", "temp: "+tmp);

        int x = (int) (width / 2 + Math.cos(angle) * mRadius - mRect.width() / 2);
        int y = (int) (height / 2 + Math.sin(angle) * mRadius - mRect.height() / 2);

        canvas.drawText(tmp, x, y, mPaint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `invalidate()` the view to see changes you made. Here is a good [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/advanced-android-training-custom-view-from-scratch/index.html?index=..%2F..advanced-android-training) to understand how to draw on canvas.